# Implementando largura máxima de um TextItem no Smart GWT 2.6

Tags: java, gwt

No SmartGWT, estou tentando fazer um `MaxLength` em um `TextItem`. Este `TextItem` fica em um campo editável de uma `Grid`. Abaixo segue o código utilizado.

Como fazer uma validação no `OnKeyPress` que, quando atinja o limite estabelecido, não permita o usuário digitar qualquer caractere a mais?

```
    final TextItem editorType = new TextItem();
    editorType.setLength(100);
    editorType.setEnforceLength(true);
    editorType.setValidateOnChange(true);
    editorType.addKeyPressHandler(new KeyPressHandler() {
        @Override
        public void onKeyPress(KeyPressEvent event) {
            if(editorType.getValue().toString().length() > 100)
                event.cancel();
        }
    });
```

Comment: Por favor, tente fazer títulos descritivos *em português*. Se achar que tem outro melhor, fique à vontade para [edit] a pergunta.

Comment: @brasofilo bem observado, havia acostumado com o stack em inglês. Obrigado!